# Issue with particles in blender donut tutorial

Tags: particles, weight-painting, normals, hair

I have been recently doing the blender donut tutorial and ran into a problem regarding the sprinkle particles. The particles (hair) keep appearing on the underside of the icing. As seen in the image below, most of the hair particles only come out from the bottom of the icing.

I tried to readjust the normals but I realised the normals were already correct. (Blue colour donut in image)

Someone suggested following through the weight painting part of the tutorial. However, the sprinkles still remain on the underside of the icing.

What is the actual problem and how do I solve this?
[image]

Particle settings below
[image]

Edit: @moonboots Thanks the hair particle problem has been solved. How do I prevent the submersion of the sprinkle particles?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your particle setting ? Can u add an image of it?

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @Nxdhin2005 Image of settings added

Comment: @moonboots just shared the file

Answer (score 4):

It has to do with the *Solidify* modifier, I guess if you leave the *Solidify* on top of the modifiers stack and don't activate the *Emission > Source > Use Modifier Stack* (which would make the object emit both on bottom and top, it's not what you want) it considers that one side must be the emitting one and not both, and it may not be the one you want. In that case maybe simply flip the normals in *Edit* mode and the particles will be displayed on the top, or put the *Solidify* modifier on the top of the modifiers stack

Comment: Emission > Source > Use Modifier Stack and Solidify on top of the modifiers stack was already applied when the problem was still persisting. I tried flipping the normals as you suggested and it worked. It's just that all my sprinkle particles are half submerged into the icing instead of being on top of the icing. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Dupli Objects** in the Particle System Render settings as it looks like it's Path now.
[image]

Also, just in case, flip normals.

Comment: My current settings is already in rendering as object and not path. I tried changing it to collections but the issue still persists

Answer (score 0):

Check the box *Only Rim* on the *Solidify/Rim* settings of the icing.