# Problem with Hair Particles in the donut Tutorial

Tags: particles

So my girlfriend was following the "Part 1, Level 2: Particles" section of the Donut Tutorial by Blender Guru.
And while using the hair particle option to use as sprinkles, she was facing this problem, where the hair particles were coming out from the below of the icing instead of top of the icing. Thus, any sprinkle particle she makes, it appears below the icing instead of top.
Why is that happening? Is there any way to fix it?

[image: Photo]

Comment: Select the icing - enter edit mode - select the whole mesh (A) - then, pick `Mesh > Normals > Flip` from the top of the viewport.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with particles in blender donut tutorial](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191165/issue-with-particles-in-blender-donut-tutorial)